# ExtJS Array issue

Tags: arrays, extjs

So I've this ExtJS checkboxgroup that I need to cycle through and check their names against some data I get from a data store, every time a user selects a product from a grid.

This is the code:

```
Ext.each(Ext.getCmp('depCheckGroup').items,function(deptm,index) {
        lookfor = deptm.id;

        if(dsDepartments.find("dept_id",lookfor) != -1) {
            deptm.checked = true;
        }
    });
```

So, again, every time a user selects a row this should fire.
Problem is that only the first click works (doesn't matter which row, it works).

The others throw an error:

```
deptm is undefined
```

If I try to get the length of the `Ext.getCmp('depCheckGroup').items` array before or after this it shows "11" which is the correct number, so I know the array isn't empty.
All JSON data loads correctly from the data store (again, it actually works for the first row selected).
Probably I'm missing something quite obvious here but I really can't see it.

Comment: we need more code, where do you use this, in a listener on what element etc..

Answer (score 2):

items is a Ext.util.MixedCollection instance.

Instead, use:

```
Ext.getCmp('depCheckGroup').each(function(comp){
    console.log(comp);
});
```